# A variable in my code doesn't seem to be incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm working on a tic tac toe game to teach myself about the canvas element, but the turn counter doesn't seem to increment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM4p7/5/)

```
function turn() {
    var turnNum = 1;
    while (turnNum <= 9) {
        alert(turnNum % 2);
        showCurrent(turnNum);

        $(canvas).click(function(event) {
            // jQuery would normalize the event
            mouse = getMouse(event);
            //now you can use the x and y positions

            if (turnNum % 2) {
                drawX(Math.floor(mouse.y / 100), Math.floor(mouse.x / 100));
            } else {
                drawO(Math.floor(mouse.y / 100), Math.floor(mouse.x / 100));
            }
        });

        turnNum = turnNum++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `turnNum++;` in your third-to-last line, not `turnNum = turnNum++;`

Comment: Thanks! It should be viewable now. The only problem is the alert statement on line 138. Leaving it in spams alerts, but taking it out crashes the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event binding has to be outside the loop (if not, you're binding multiple times), Should be like this:

```
var turnNum;
$(canvas).click(function(event) {
    // jQuery would normalize the event
    mouse = getMouse(event);
    //now you can use the x and y positions
    if (turnNum % 2) {
        drawX(Math.floor(mouse.y / 100), Math.floor(mouse.x / 100));
    } else {
        drawO(Math.floor(mouse.y / 100), Math.floor(mouse.x / 100));
    }
 });
function turn() {
   turnNum = 1;
   while (turnNum <= 9) {
      alert(turnNum % 2);
      showCurrent(turnNum);      
      turnNum++;
   }
}
```

Note that we took out the turnNum var so it's accessible but the event listener.
Also, your turnNum increment was wrong.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: This helped a lot! It's still giving me all Os, tho. Is that because the incremented turnNum is only accessible inside the turn() function?

Comment: Oh, now I understand your problem. Maybe the turn method isn't needed. Here you have the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/tM4p7/8/

Answer (score 1):

You issue could be with this statement `turnNum = turnNum++;` It is a post increment operator which mean it assigns and then increments but then assignments sets it back to 1 itself always, just use `turnNum++` or you probably meant to use `turnNum += 1`

Apart from that another issue is that in the loop you are binding the click event to `canvas` and using the shared variable `turnNum` inside that which means by the time your click event runs it would always be having the last value and it seems like you are binding the same click event multiple times to the same `canvas`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
turnNum = turnNum++;
```

please use just

```
turnNum++;
```

Answer (score 1):

While both the answers about **how** you're incrementing `turnNum` are correct, there's an even more fundamental issue about **when** you're doing so.

You need to update this variable during the click event.  And you definitely don't want to be rebinding that click event over and over.  So you need some significant restructuring of this logic.

### Update

This is one simple way to restructure the code.  Remove the `turn` function, and after the `drawGrid` call, use this instead:

```
var turnNum = 0;
showCurrent(turnNum);

$(canvas).click(function(event) {
    if(turnNum++ < 9) {
        showCurrent(turnNum);
    }
    mouse = getMouse(event);
    //now you can use the x and y positions

    if(turnNum%2) {
        drawX(Math.floor(mouse.y/100),Math.floor(mouse.x/100));
    } else {
        drawO(Math.floor(mouse.y/100),Math.floor(mouse.x/100));
    }
});
```

There's a version that seems to be working correctly on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tM4p7/7/)**.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp

As you can see in the link, the ++ increments the variable only after assigning it.

Do:

```
turnNum = ++turnNum;
```

Or simply:

```
turnNum++;
```

Comment: Do remove the first part. It's superflous, the ++ operator already assigns the incremented value to the variable. There is no need for the double assignment (implicit and explicit)

Comment: True... I will leave it with the comment though, so others can learn